# Debian install via network(not Internet)

Tags: linux, debian

How i can install debian over my local network using only installation files located on nfs or samba directory?

I build pxe+tftpd+nfs server. Download debian netboot-installer, but it's download all files via Internet.

Comment: The following pages might be of interest: [Setup Local Repositories with ‘apt-mirror’ in Ubuntu and Debian Systems](http://www.tecmint.com/setup-local-repositories-in-ubuntu/) and [Setting up a Debian archive mirror](https://www.debian.org/mirror/ftpmirror) Also, answers to [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/68182/55900) could be helpful.